# Procedimientos almacenados (visual basic.net) y Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, .net

**CLASS CONEXION**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Conexion

Protected cnn As New MySqlConnection

Public idusuario As Integer

Protected Function conectado()
    Try
        cnn = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Uid=root; Database=bdoperador")
        cnn.Open()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Protected Function desconectado()
    Try
        If cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Close()
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
End Class
```

**CLASS FCLIENTE**

```
Public Class fcliente
Inherits Conexion
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

Public Function mostrar() As DataTable
    Try
        conectado()

        cmd = New MySqlCommand("mostrar_cliente")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection = cnn



        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            Return dt
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        desconectado()
    End Try
  End Function
  End Class
```

Mi procedimiento almacenado es **mostrar_cliente**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mostrar_cliente()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY idcliente desc;
END
```

si lo hago  de esa forma me sale error en el mysql
ahora si lo creo así

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mostrar_cliente()
SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY idcliente desc;
```

no me sale error pero no sucede nada en el formulario
pero si hago un select solamente por ejemplo

```
SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY idcliente desc
```

ahí si carga los datos al formulario
quisiera saber porque no carga los datos cuando lo  hago de un procedimiento.

Answer (score 1):

En la parte que dice:

```
If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
```

Cámbiala por:

```
If cmd.ExecuteReader Then
```

El `ExecuteNonQuery` se utiliza cuando no quieres que te retorne resultados, por ejemplo `UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE` a diferencia del `ExecuteReader` que retorna un conjunto de registros dependiendo de la consulta.

Espero que sea de utilidad, Saludos.